# UITesting in iOS: tap() method doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, ui-testing, ios10.3.2

### I am facing a strange problem with UITesting in Swift under iOS 10.3.2 and Xcode 8.3.3 .

I am running a simple test inside my app which should tap and verify every single row inside a TableView (is the Settings view of my application so every single row is loaded from the disk and nothing is downloaded from the web at this step), but for a strange reason when I tap on a row which previously wasn't visible the .tap() method doesn't work.

Example Code:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()  

let myTableView = app.tables.element(matching: .table, identifier:    "tableView01")  
myTableView.swipeUp(). //I swipe so that the cell becomes visible...  

let myCell = myTableView.cells.element(matching: .cell, identifier: "tappableCell")  

myCell.tap()
```

---

The strange thing is that **I have a correct output from the console in Xcode**.

```
 t =   328.24s     Tap "tappableCell" Cell
    t =   328.24s         Wait for app to idle
    t =   328.80s         Find the "tappableCell" Cell
    t =   328.80s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.thefloow.enterprise.ownbrand
    t =   328.92s             Find: Descendants matching type Table
    t =   328.92s             Find: Element at index 0
    t =   328.92s             Find: Descendants matching type Cell
    t =   328.92s             Find: Elements matching predicate '"tappableCell" IN identifiers'
    t =   329.04s             Wait for app to idle
    t =   329.22s         Synthesize event
    t =   329.37s         Wait for app to idle
```

Another strange thing is that if **I put a breakpoint before the tap method and then I run it from the command line it works perfectly giving me the same output from the console.**

What could be the reason of this strange behaviour?

---

Thank you for your help!
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem is in the framework. After scrolling the UI doesn't respond properly so I had to double tap on the cell to resign the UIResponder and then the test works properly. I've also reported the issue to  to know if it is a regular behaviour or not.

However thank you to everyone! Happy coding!